# Where is installation directory of the apps which were created by Windows App Studio?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Anyone knows where is installation directory of the apps which were created by Windows App Studio, apparently, it's not in c:\Data\Programs{ApplicationId}.., for example, if you installed this app "[AppStudio Contoso Sample App](http://www.windowsphone.com/zh-cn/store/app/appstudio-contoso-sample-app/5bd39cf7-4dc6-44f7-a9db-8c9b5f939a62)", I want to know its install location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the location of the installed package,

[Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx)